# How to get weight from serial port?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a WPF application which has a module for weighing loads. Since the serial port communication varies from one weighbridge to the other, I want to make the weighing module a separate  dll.

I am creating a class library where I use the serial port for weighing loads. I need to return back the weight to the main program.

```
double GetWeights()
{

 spWeigh = new SerialPort("COM1", 2400, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            spWeigh.RtsEnable = false;
            spWeigh.DtrEnable = false;
            spWeigh.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            spWeigh.ReadTimeout = 10000;
            spWeigh.DataReceived +=spWeigh_DataReceived;

}
```

But the data receieved is in a different thread. How will I get the weight back in my main program?

```
 void spWeigh_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
      // code here
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not add an event to the library that your main program subscribes to and which is raised by your library, passing back the required data?

In your library:

```
class YourLibrary
{
    public delegate void RawDataEventHandler(object sender, RawDataEventArgs e);
    public event RawDataEventHandler RawDataReceived;

    void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string ReceivedData = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
        if (RawDataReceived != null)
            RawDataReceived(this, new RawDataEventArgs(ReceivedData));
    }
}

class RawDataEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Data { private set; get; }

    public RawDataEventArgs(string data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

In your main program:

```
class MainProgram
{
    YourLibrary library = new YourLibrary();
    library.RawDataReceived += new YourLibrary.RawDataEventHandler(library_RawDataReceived);

    void library_RawDataReceived(object sender, RawDataEventArgs e)
    {
        // Your code here - the data passed back is in e.Data
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how do I subscribe to the event from the main program

Comment: Updated my answer - you'll have to change the names to suit

Answer (score 0):

If the data does not need to be fast (i.e. less than once a second) you could write to a text file in one thread and read from it in the main thread